# Adding count label for gg barplot with stat = 'identity'

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I have a GGbarplot `geom_bar()` with a x and a y value and using `stat = 'identity`.
I want to be able to print the y-axis-value in the graph. This should be really simple i guess, but i can't figure out why it won't work.

plot is build using this simple line (see below for a subset of the dataset):

```
 library(tidyverse)
   df %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = timeunit, y = pa, group = main_grp ))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = main_grp),stat = 'identity')
```

I'm trying to add labels using:

```
geom_text(aes(label= pa), y=0, stat='identity', colour="white", size=4, vjust = -2)
```

this wont work since it will just print all the 0's and 1's in the dataset.

I tried using

```
geom_text(aes(label= group_by(timeunit) %>% summarise (sum = sum(pa), y=0, stat='identity', colour="white", size=4, vjust = -2)
```

to be able to print a label per timeunit, but this also won't give me any desired result.
./
I also tried making a simple vector with the sum of all 1's per timeunit, ending up with a vector of length 6 (total number of timeunits), but i can't use this to label because it is of a different length than the dataset.

My question:
How can i print the value of the y axis in my barchart? Preferably also print labels within the fill to show how many counts there are per subset.

dput of subsample dataset:

```
structure(list(Soort.wetenschappelijk = c("Pastinaca sativa subsp. sativa", 
"Leymus arenarius", "Limonium humile", "Carex acuta", "Silene flos-cuculi", 
"Smyrnium olusatrum", "Stellaria graminea", "Vicia sativa ssp. sativa", 
"Brassica rapa", "Viola curtisii", "Pyrola minor", "Cerastium semidecandrum", 
"Genista tinctoria", "Anthemis cotula", "Juncus gerardii", "Coronopus squamatus", 
"Lonicera periclymenum", "Mentha arvensis", "Aphanes australis", 
"Onopordum acanthium", "Polypodium vulgare", "Hyacinthoides non-scripta", 
"Juncus acutiflorus", "Persicaria hydropiper", "Dactylorhiza majalis subsp. praetermissa", 
"Cerastium diffusum", "Stellaria pallida", "Potamogeton lucens", 
"Scleranthus annuus subsp. polycarpos", "Geum urbanum", "Ceratocapnos claviculata", 
"Dryopteris cristata", "Potamogeton gramineus", "Silene dioica", 
"Dactylorhiza majalis subsp. praetermissa", "Rumex crispus", 
"Gentiana pneumonanthe", "Mespilus germanica", "Huperzia selago", 
"Veronica chamaedrys", "Veronica persica", "Stachys sylvatica", 
"Drosera intermedia", "Puccinellia distans subsp. distans", "Vicia lathyroides", 
"Berula erecta", "Hyacinthoides non-scripta", "Carex acuta", 
"Erica scoparia", "Echinochloa crus-galli"), Oeco.groep = c("5a", 
"3a", "3c", "4c", "5b", "8b", "5a", "5a", "1e", "6b", "9e", "6b", 
"7e", "1e", "3c", "1d", "9e", "2a", "1c", "1f", "9e", "9c", "5b", 
"2b", "5b", "3a", "8b", "4a", "1c", "8b", "9e", "7a", "4b", "8b", 
"5b", "2a", "7d", "8d", "7e", "5a", "1a", "9b", "7d", "3b", "6b", 
"4c", "9c", "4c", "7e", "1c"), time_unit = c("X1940.x", "X1900.x", 
"X1975.x", "X1900.x", "X1993.x", "X1993.x", "X1993.x", "X1940.x", 
"X2001.x", "X1920.x", "X1993.x", "X1975.x", "X1993.x", "X1920.x", 
"X2001.x", "X1920.x", "X1900.x", "X1993.x", "X1993.x", "X1993.x", 
"X1993.x", "X2001.x", "X2001.x", "X2001.x", "X2001.x", "X2001.x", 
"X1975.x", "X1940.x", "X1993.x", "X1993.x", "X1940.x", "X1993.x", 
"X1975.x", "X1993.x", "X1940.x", "X1900.x", "X2001.x", "X1940.x", 
"X1993.x", "X1900.x", "X2001.x", "X1940.x", "X1920.x", "X1940.x", 
"X1920.x", "X1993.x", "X1900.x", "X1993.x", "X2001.x", "X1993.x"
), pa = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), timeunit = c("1940", "1900", 
"1975", "1900", "1993", "1993", "1993", "1940", "2001", "1920", 
"1993", "1975", "1993", "1920", "2001", "1920", "1900", "1993", 
"1993", "1993", "1993", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", 
"1975", "1940", "1993", "1993", "1940", "1993", "1975", "1993", 
"1940", "1900", "2001", "1940", "1993", "1900", "2001", "1940", 
"1920", "1940", "1920", "1993", "1900", "1993", "2001", "1993"
), main_grp = c("5", "3", "3", "4", "5", "8", "5", "5", "1", 
"6", "9", "6", "7", "1", "3", "1", "9", "2", "1", "1", "9", "9", 
"5", "2", "5", "3", "8", "4", "1", "8", "9", "7", "4", "8", "5", 
"2", "7", "8", "7", "5", "1", "9", "7", "3", "6", "4", "9", "4", 
"7", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try creating the labels in a different dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Labels
labs <- df %>% group_by(timeunit) %>%
  summarise(N=sum(pa)) %>% mutate(main_grp=NA)
#Plot
df %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = timeunit, y = pa, group = main_grp))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = main_grp),stat = 'identity')+
  geom_text(data=labs,aes(label=N,y=N),vjust=-0.5)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Duck, this works. I made the mistake of not adding an NA list for fill in my own tries. Great!

Comment: @Stevestingray Great! It is also a fantastic question +1